# How to get image path from HTML by tag (using Jsoup)

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I'm tring to get image url src from tag `<img>`

E.g I have this html data from facebook:

```
<img class="profilePic img" alt="Facebook Developers" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p320x320/9988_10151403325753553_1486509350_n.png?oh=ecdfcf4b449779941db77b52950843b3&amp;oe=568F1F42&amp;__gda__=1453778308_a1ffaea01e68e9dade86f1b11989a50d">
```

How can I get only image src with the **class="profilePic img"** attribute or class name? Any idea how do I get it? I'm using Jsoup library.

Comment: scrapping? Anna it is not allowed

Comment: Have you tried using CSS selectors with `select` method? Tutorial: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the images by calling `getElementsByTag('img')` and then call `select(".your_class_name")` to get only the images with the specified class (or any other query)

e.g:

```
Jsoup.connect("http://stackexchange.com").get().getElementsByTag("img").select(".favicon")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 Document document = Jsoup.connect("yourLink").get();
 String img_url = document.select("img[class=profilePic img]").first().attr("src");
 Log.d('Src image: ', img_url);
```

Remember: solve it in other thread, not main thread :)

Answer (score 0):

JSoup CSS offers multiple class selection through concatenation. The CSS selector for the classes are  `.profilePic` and `.img`. Selecting both classes means concatenating: `.profilePic.img`. So this should be your code:

```
 document.select("img.profilePic.img")
```

This is better than `img[class=profilePic img]`, because the latter will look for exactly the string "profilePic img". Classes however may appear in different order or with more spaces in the document you parse.

To get to the src attributes of all img elements you need to loop over the results:

```
Elements imgs = document.select("img.profilePic.img");
for (Element img : imgs){
    String srcStr = img.attr("src");
    //do what ever you need to do with srcStr 
}
```